# Convert stream BigDecimal summing to JavaFX Property

Tags: java, javafx, data-binding

I have a problem trying to convert a bigdecimal to ObjectProperty

```
public class LinePiece {

    private int idLine;
    private ObjectProperty<BigDecimal> qty = new SimpleObjectProperty<BigDecimal>(BigDecimal.ZERO);
    private ObjectProperty<BigDecimal> price = new SimpleObjectProperty<BigDecimal>(BigDecimal.ZERO);
    private ObjectProperty<BigDecimal> remise = new SimpleObjectProperty<BigDecimal>(BigDecimal.ZERO);
    private IntegerProperty tva = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
    private ObjectProperty<BigDecimal> subTotal = new SimpleObjectProperty<BigDecimal>(BigDecimal.ZERO);
// Getters and Setters
}
```

We have a set of items of type LinePiece

```
private Set<LinePiece> LinePieces = new HashSet<>();
  LinePieces .add(new LinePiece());
  LinePieces .add(new LinePiece());
  LinePieces .add(new LinePiece());
```

After implementing summing to the actual set:

```
BigDecimal sum = lineCommande.stream().map(LineCommande::getSubTotal)
                .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO,BigDecimal::add);
```

I want to make sum observable, so i can listen for sum changes.
How i can acheive this ?

Remark: I can't use ObservableList here because i'm using hibernate

```
 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "piece", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<LinePiece> LinePieces = new HashSet<>();
```

if there another solution using ObservableList please tell me.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Hibernate, but assuming you must use a `Set` object, can't you use [`ObservableSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ObservableSet.html) ?

Answer (score 0):

Create an `ObjectBinding<BigInteger>` (which implements `ObservableValue<BigInteger>`):

```
ObjectBinding<BigInteger> sum = new ObjectBinding<BigInteger>() {
    {
        lineCommande.stream().forEach(l -> bind(l.subTotalProperty()));
    }

    @Override
    protected BigInteger computeValue() {
        return lineCommande.stream().map(LineCommande::getSubTotal)
                .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO,BigDecimal::add);
    }
};
```

Comment: I'm using BigDecimal not BigInteger , i tried to change it BigDecimal, but it seems not working !!